# Try catch blocks for creating summary counts in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a summary dataframe that reflects the number of tracked and untracked boxes. Simple:

```
                       School - Exams Tracked    School - Exams Not Tracked
All Box Tracked Sites                    5820                             2
```

We will use this report during dropoff times, so sometimes there will be no tracked boxes, and after some time all the boxes will be tracked.

Right now I may receive a key error with my code (`.get_loc(key)`), because sometimes it looks for 'TRACKED' which doesn't exist yet at the moment.

This is the best solution I came up with but I feel it's ugly:

```py
BoxTrackingSummary_df = pd.DataFrame()
BoxTrackingSummary_df_columns = ['School - Exams Tracked', 'School - Exams Not Tracked']

summary_group = pd.DataFrame(BoxTrackingReport_df.groupby('Tracked At A Site?').agg('count')['All Box Tracked Sites'])

# group.loc can only count groups that exist. plan for when there are no 'TRACKED' or no 'NO's, or receive a .get_loc(key) error
try:
    BoxTrackingSummary_df['School - Exams Tracked'] = summary_group.loc['TRACKED']
except:
    BoxTrackingSummary_df['School - Exams Tracked'] = 0
    print('No Tracked yet.')

try:
    BoxTrackingSummary_df['School - Exams Not Tracked'] = summary_group.loc['NO']
except:
    BoxTrackingSummary_df['School - Exams Not Tracked'] = 0
    print('All Tracked.')
```

This is what the report column 'Tracked At A Site?' looks like:

```
>>> BoxTrackingReport_df['Tracked At A Site?']
...
0       TRACKED
1       TRACKED
2       TRACKED
3       TRACKED
4       TRACKED
```

Comment: Can you share the `All Box Tracked Sites` column from `BoxTrackingReport_df` since it's used in the `summary_group` definition.

Comment: Please post input data and full data frame desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for `try/except` or to initialize an empty data frame and assign columns from a separate `groupby` data frame. Consider working directly from *Tracked At A Site?* column (i.e., series):

```
BoxTrackingSummary_df = (BoxTrackingReport_df['Tracked At A Site?'] 
                             .rename('All Box Tracked Sites')
                             .value_counts()
                             .to_frame()
                             .transpose()
                             .reindex(columns=['TRACKED', 'NO'])  
                             .fillna(0)
                             .set_axis(['School - Exams Tracked', 'School - Exams Not Tracked'], 
                                        axis='columns', inplace=False)
                        )
```

To demonstrate with random, seeded data

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(882019)
BoxTrackingReport_df = pd.DataFrame({'Tracked At A Site?': np.random.choice(['TRACKED', 'NO'], 500)})
...

print(BoxTrackingSummary_df)

#                        School - Exams Tracked  School - Exams Not Tracked
# All Box Tracked Sites                     251                         249
```

---

With `reindex` above, code always ensures both columns appear regardless if they are in data or not (add `.fillna(0)`

```
BoxTrackingReport_df = pd.DataFrame({'Tracked At A Site?': np.repeat(['TRACKED'], 500)})
...

print(BoxTrackingSummary_df)

#                        School - Exams Tracked  School - Exams Not Tracked
# All Box Tracked Sites                     500                         0.0
```